# How to add more than one firebase sort

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to do double filtering related to Firestore. I have a city selection button and the second one is a ListView that selects the products category.

My category filtering works well, but I don't know how to add more city filtering for it.

[image: ListView of categories]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68SIS.png)

I tried to write something like this

```
stocks.where('city', arrayContains: 'Chicago').where('tags', arrayContains: 'All');
```

But this is wrong. I will be grateful for any answer.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code:

```
stocks.where('city', arrayContains: 'Chicago').where('tags', arrayContains: 'All');
```

Will not work, because there is a [query limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) that says:

> You can use at most one array-contains clause per query. You can't combine array-contains with array-contains-any.

So you can use **only** one `arrayContains` in a query.

To solve this, you should consider using maps, and not arrays, a case in which the following database schema will do the trick:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- stocks
         |
         --- $stockId
                |
                --- cities
                |    |
                |    --- "Chicago": true
                |
                --- tags
                     |
                     --- "All": true
```

Then a query like the one below will work perfectly fine:

```
stocks.whereEqualTo("cities.Chicago", true).whereEqualTo("tags.All", true);
```

Comment: Hey Skeleteenx. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: salute), I just generally divided into collections, I'll try your version. Thanks for the explanation and answer